# Redhat No package make available

Tags: linux, redhat

I am using redhat and I need to install make. But yum don't find the make package :

```
# yum install make --verbose
Config time: 0.059
Yum Version: 3.2.22
Setting up Package Sacks
pkgsack time: 0.084
rpmdb time: 0.000
Setting up Install Process
Checking for virtual provide or file-provide for make
Searching pkgSack for dep: make
No package make available.
Nothing to do
```

I tried to install group Development Tools too :

```
# yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
Setting up Group Process
Failed to add groups file for repository: epel - comps file is empty/damaged
Warning: Group Development Tools does not exist.
No packages in any requested group available to install or update
```

My repolist are the following :

```
# yum repolist
epel                                                                  | 3.7 kB     00:00
rhel-source                                                           | 2.6 kB     00:00
rpmforge                                                              | 1.9 kB     00:00
repo id                    repo name                                           status
epel                       Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64      6,733
rhel-source                Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5Server - Source           0
rpmforge                   RHEL 5Server - RPMforge.net - dag                   11,403
repolist: 18,136
```

Comment: Are you using Red Hat, or something like CentOS? If you're using Red Hat, is your system attached to an active subscription?  What is the output of `yum repolist`?

Comment: check ur repo configs http://wiki.centos.org/Using_protectbase_and_fastestmirror_yum_plugins

Comment: Yes, I am using Red Hat 5.7. I edit my post with the result of yum reposlit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added base Red Hat repository with the following commands :

```
cd /etc/yum.repo.d
wget http://public-yum.oracle.com/public-yum-el5.repo
cd /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/
wget https://public-yum.oracle.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle-el5
```

Now yum install make works.

Comment: if GPG key retrieval failed with error No such file or directory: '/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle', then run this:    

"wget https://public-yum.oracle.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle-el5 -O /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle --no-check-certificate" (without quotes)

Comment: Use http instead of https for the GPG retrieval and it will work.